# Calculate mean of dependent variable from a given linear regression model based on given values of independent variables in R

Tags: r, regression, lm

I have built a interactive model to predict `child.iq` with `mother.age` and `mother.highschool`:

```
fit <- lm(child.iq ~ mother.highschool + mother.age + mother.highschool:mother.age, data = df)
# Summarize the model
summary(fit)
```

Out:

```
Call:
lm(formula = child.iq ~ mother.highschool + mother.age + mother.highschool:mother.age, 
    data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-55.535 -12.734   2.414  14.150  54.377 

Coefficients:
                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  110.5417    16.4538   6.718 5.85e-11 ***
mother.highschool            -41.2875    18.9920  -2.174  0.03025 *  
mother.age                    -1.5220     0.7532  -2.021  0.04391 *  
mother.highschool:mother.age   2.3911     0.8567   2.791  0.00549 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 19.7 on 430 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.07467,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.06822 
F-statistic: 11.57 on 3 and 430 DF,  p-value: 2.64e-07
```

Now, I was asked to use the fitted model above, calculate the mean child IQ when mother’s age is equal to 30 and when the mother did not complete high school.

Someone could give me some tips and help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are talking about the mean prediction on this subsample. You are looking for the `predict` function:

```r
df$pred <- predict(fit)
mean(df$pred[(df$mother.age == 30) & (df$mother.highschool==0)], na.rm = TRUE)
``̀
```

Comment: How about this? `predict(m2, newdata = list(mother.age = 30, mother.highschool = '1'))`?

Comment: Cannot test it but not sure it works because you also need other variables. If you don't want to predict on the whole dataframe, you can do: `predict(fit, newdata = df[(df$mother.age == 30) & (df$mother.highschool==0), ])`

Comment: Thanks, I'll test and let you know.

Comment: With my code, I get `1, 64.8813 ` on two lines, while with your code, I get `86.79724`.